# Overlay arrow on fixed-width text

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to write a text editor cheatsheet that shows the result of movement commands from one character where the cursor is to another character in the text, perhaps on a different line.

The text would be fixed-width code, so the canvas could be considered to be an `N x N` grid. Ideally I want some tool that can draw an arrow from one position in this grid to another position.

There are miscellaneous considerations such as whether I could do better than a rasterized image of the text + overlaid arrow, or whether I could do something fancy like render the text as text and then overlay a transparent SVG image with a vectorized arrow.

As a mostly backend server-side engineer, I find tasks like this particularly tough. So any help would be greatly appreciated. (Happy to post this question elsewhere if this is not the correct place, or add any detail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a grid, as you say, you should know x,y coordinates for the start and end of the line. Those translate to x1,y1 and x2,y2 attributes on the svg line below:

```css
html {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.text {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

.text svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 120%;
}

.text,
.text svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non-provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio.


  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 150">
  
    <defs>
      <pattern id="smallGrid" y="12" width="7.8" height="15" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <path d="M 15 0 L 0 0 0 15" fill="none" stroke="rgba(50,0,255,0.3)" stroke-width="0.5"/>
      </pattern>
      <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#f00" />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    
    <rect width="400" height="150" fill="url(#smallGrid)" />
    <line x1="39" y1="12" x2="156" y2="68" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />

  </svg>
</p>
```

Comment: This helps a lot. How to overlay the line(s) with the text? Putting the SVG as a background would hide the lines. I want to put the SVG in the foreground of the `<div>` that contains the text. Probably best if I ask a separate question but thought I'd take a chance here.

Comment: @user2297550 An overlay would be one option, maybe the best option. Using svg text is also an option, but it's hard to say which would work best without a better understanding of your implementation

Comment: @user2297550 I updated the snippet to include text, and an overlay with a grid (just for clarification), and the arrow.

Comment: Gorgeous, thank you! I'll take it from here. The remaining challenge for me is to curve the lines when the source and destination are on the same line. IThat would be for showing how an editor movement command on the same line would work.) But since I know the building blocks (paths), I can do it myself. Thanks :-)